# Object does not have attribute when using reduce (but works on map)

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.x = data[0]
        self.y = data[1]
```

And I try this in the interpreter:

```
>>> a = Test([1,2])
>>> b = Test([1,2])
>>> c = Test([1,2])
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x.x + y.x, [a,b,c])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Although this works:

```
>>> map(lambda x: x.x, [a,b,c])
[1, 1, 1]
```

Compiler version: Python 2.7

Comment: `x.x + y.x` Here, `x` is `int` (it is 1) and it *doesn't* have `x` attribute (`y` is the same).

Comment: @MarounMaroun How `x` is `int` ? Isn't x the object `Test` there ?

Comment: @Sibi: no, it is not, not beyond the first call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how `reduce()` works; `x` is the *result so far*. Your `lambda` is returning integers, so `x` is bound to an integer, not a `Test` instance, after the first call.

`reduce()` does this for your input:

1. take `a` and `b` and pass that to the lambda. Take the return value as the accumulated result.
2. take `c` and pass the accumulated result and `c` to the lambda. The accumulated result is an integer and your call fails.

If you need it to be a `Test` object, always, return one:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: Test([x.x + y.x, 0]), [a, b, c])
```

Now the accumulated value has a `.x` attribute *too*.

The alternative is to use integers all the way through, by giving `reduce()` an initial value for the accumulator:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y.x, [a, b, c], 0)
```

Now `x` is always going to be an integer, starting with `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` is cumulative. So it takes the *result* of the previous expression and adds to it. From the help on `reduce`:

> reduce(...)
>       reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
>
> ```
> Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
> from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
> For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
> ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
> of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
> sequence is empty.
> ```

The key phrase is this: `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`.

So after the first calculation, the result (an integer) is used, and since integers don't have `x`, you get the exception.